# Get incoming number and do query - Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this code to receive the caller number and do query in side case `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING` 
I already get the caller number but when i want to do query in side the case the app will give me error i don't know why can any one help me please to solve the problem

this is my code

```
public class IncomingCallReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

protected static final String TAG = "SWAJ";
private Context mContext;
private Intent mIntent;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG ," onCallStateChanged ");
    mContext = context;
    mIntent = intent;
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int events = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE;
    tm.listen(phoneStateListener, events);
}

private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        switch (state) {

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

            SilentMeDB databaseHelper = new SilentMeDB(mContext);   
            SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.query("events",null,null, null, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            while(!c.isAfterLast())
               {        
                try
                   {                
                      Log.d(TAG, "Message is  " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Message") ));
                   }
                catch(Exception e)
                     {
                       Log.d("Exp", e.getMessage());
                     }         
                c.moveToNext();                                
               } c.close();     
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

        }

        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
};

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Comment: What's the error you're getting? What does the logcat say?

Comment: @exilimex: please post your logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to move query code up into the on receive method. I don't see any reason to be using a listener here. Besides, the moment your onReceive function ends that listener is going to go away and won't be listening anymore. In your onReceive you can check the Intent you get to see if the call state is ringing and then conditionally execute your code.